# Alternative ways to move money out of mtgox

Tags: mtgox, transaction-fees, withdrawal

Apparently withdrawals from MtGox are currently taking at least four weeks and probably at least eight weeks.  Would it be possible to establish an account on some other site than MtGox, then move bitcoins quickly from MtGox to that other site, the sell them and withdraw dollars quickly?  What sites, what fees, and what amounts of time would be involved?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of other exchanges besides MtGox, and you could move your bitcoins from MtGox to any of them.  So are you just asking for a list of exchanges with convenient USD withdrawal schemes?  I think that question has been answered many times before.

Comment: Note that there's a catch: it seems, by usual laws of supply and demand, that on exchanges with easier USD withdrawal, bitcoins trade at lower prices.  (Conversely, this is probably why prices on MtGox are much higher than elsewhere.)  So you probably won't get as many dollars for your coins as you would on MtGox.